# Как сделать чтобы знак '=' был слева в кнопке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы `=` был слева?

```css
#go{
    background: grey;
    border: none;
    font-size: 3vw;
    height: 4.5vw;
    width: 5.3vw;
    text-align: left;


}
```

```html
 <div class="sos"><input id="go" onclick="senddat();" type="submit" name="go" value="=" ><div id="resp"></div></div>
```

Comment: Ну что за манера постить скриншот всего экрана?! Просто желтый прямоугольник нельзя было вырезать? Этого достаточно.

Comment: У меня, кстати, знак "=" слева.

Comment: Очевидно проблема не в этом участке кода, возможно нужно переопределить какое-то наследуемое свойство, о котором мы не знаем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите свойство - padding: 0;

```css
#go {
  background: grey;
  border: none;
  font-size: 3vw;
  height: 4.5vw;
  width: 5.3vw;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sos"><input id="go" onclick="senddat();" type="submit" name="go" value="=">
  <div id="resp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: каким образом right может помочь сделать текст _слева_?

Comment: @Grundy, это непостижимо для человеческого ума:)